# Why "continue" function in loop throws error when (k+1) is used as k (variable) value?

Tags: javascript, do-while, continue

I hope YOU guys are doing good
I am learning Javascript
I got to know about "continue" which we can use in loop for iteration.
But here is what i can't get

First have a look at the code:

```js
let k = 1

do {
  if (k === 9) {
    k++;
    continue;
  }
  console.log(k + 1);
  k++;
} while (k < 15);
```

When in console.log is (k+1)then, 9 is printed and 10 is missed.
Can't get why?

But when this code is used

```js
let k = 1

do {
  if (k === 9) {
    k++;
    continue;
  }
  console.log(k);
  k++;
} while (k < 15);
```

When in console.log is (k)then, 9 is not printed and 10 is printed.

Can't understand the logic behind when simple (k) is used and when (k+1) is used?

So this is what i understood is. That if K=1. console.log(k+1). 2 is printed. and then due to k++. k becomes 2 and condition is tested and as it is true so it will move to another loop. And this continues. Right?

Thanks

Comment: I think the continue misses out the console log in both examples when `k` is `9`. The only difference I see is what the log outputs

Comment: it's standard loop syntax found in most language with for loops. See the docs for `continue` to understand how it works and how to use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue - when you see `continue`, you see an instruction to _immediately_ stop and move on to the next iteration. No further code in the loop body runs.

Comment: It continues past logging when `k==9`. So if it logs `k+1` it doesn't log `9+1=10` and when it logs `k` it doesn't log `9=9`.

Comment: Admittedly, continue is somewhat dubiously named, it typically is used for continue past the loop; a person not knowing this could well think it meant continue in the loop, but I guess that would be redundant, and is the opposite of what it means in this context!

Comment: @Barmar continue stops the execution of the statements in the current iteration and moves ahead.
What i don't understand is that
In code number 1 when k===9, then 9 should be not printed and it should move ahead to 10.
And it is done exactly done like this.
But in code number 2 , 9 is printed but 10 is not printed so it confuses me why in code number 1, 9 is not printed and in code number 2, 9 is printed.

Comment: @BehindTheWebPage in code number 1, `9` is printed when `k == 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you're logging the value of `k+1` so, when k is 1 it logs the value 2 (1+1), when k is 2 it logs the value 3 (2+1) all the way up to where k is 8 and logs 9 (8+1). When k is 9 though, k is still incremented and `k+1` is 10 but this doesn't get logged because the rest of the loop is skipped.

In the second example, you're doing exactly the same thing but loggin the value of `k` not `k+1` so all the logged values are 1 less.

***"...can YOU also explain k++ under console.log(k+1)"***

In both cases the value of k is incremented by 1 each time around the loops either at the end of the block, after the `console.log` or inside the `if (k === 9)` block before `continue`

Comment: Thanks for explaining
Got YOUR point
But can YOU also explain k++ under console.log(k+1).
As i thought when k=1
It will do console.log(k+1) = 2
and print
And now it will do what is written under console.log which k++.
So i would really appreciate if YOU can also explain k++ under console.log(k+1).

Comment: @BehindTheWebPage `k+1` does not modify `k` value, `k++` is equivalent to `k+=1` which is equivalent to `k = k + 1`. In the second case you assign the value `k+1` to k, while in the first case you just give `k+1` as an argument to `console.log`.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Okay got it.
So can YOU please explain this ( k +1 as an argument to console.log ).
As i was thinking that when k = 1 declared.
It is printed as 2 due to ( console.log (k+1) ).
then i get confuse on that, samething is done by k++.
Actually i am learning this from a channel on Youtube and that guy didn't explained this deeply.
So that's why i am asking question to just clear the base concept.

Comment: Nope, `k+1` returns the value 2 but it does not change the value of `k` unlike `k++` which is effectively (but not exactly) the same as `k = k + 1` - see the difference

Comment: Thanks.
So this is what i understood is.
That if K=1.
console.log(k+1).
2 is printed.
and then due to k++.
k becomes 2 and condition is tested and as it is true so it will move to another loop.
And this continues.
Right?

Comment: yep, that's right

Answer (score 6):

`continue` skips the rest of the loop body and starts the next iteration of the loop (if the `while` condition is still true).

In both code snippets, you do this when `k == 9`, so it skips over the code that calls `console.log()`.

In the first version, it logs `k+1`. So when `k == 9` it skips printing `10`.

In the second version, it logs `k`. So when `k == 9` it skips printing `9`.

Comment: Thanks BARMAR
So what does then k++ do in If statement
What's its use there?

Comment: It adds 1 to `k`. You need to do that in the `if` statement because you're skipping the `k++` later in the loop. If you don't do it, then the loop will be stuck at `k == 9`.

Answer (score 4):

That is because in your logic, if `k === 9`, you add +1 to `k` and then log it to console, which makes 9 invisible. You should log it and then add `k++`.

Comment: If you log it before the `if`, how are you supposed to see any difference done by the existence of the `continue`?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine It is loged in after "If"

Comment: @BehindTheWebPage yes, in the question, but this answer suggested to put the log before the `k++` which could be at two positions: before the `if` which means you will just log `k` on each iteration  (the `if` and `continue` become useless) or inside the `if` which means you will always log only 9.